# How to run NestJS migrations in GCP Cloud Run

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS application deployed in Google Cloud Run and I was able to connect to the Cloud SQL database but I'm having trouble running the TypeORM migrations. Instead of using `ormconfig.json`, I created a `database.config.ts` file that exports a TypeORM connection object so that it can be loaded asynchronously with:

```
import { config } from './config/database.config';
...
imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => config,
    }),
]
```

My `database.config.ts` file contains the following:

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';
import 'reflect-metadata';

export const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

export const config: ConnectionOptions = {
  name: 'default',
  type: 'mysql' as any,
  driver: 'mysql',
  database: 'test_db',
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'migrations',
  },
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',

  // Production Mode
  ...(prod && {
    extra: {
      socketPath: '/cloudsql/{PROJECT_ID}:us-central1:{DB_NAME}',
    },
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: true,
    migrationsRun: false,
    migrations: ['dist/migrations/*{.js}'],
    cli: { migrationsDir: 'src/migrations' },
  }),
};

export default config;
```

The Dockerfile used to initialize the Cloud Run instance has the following:

```
# use node 12 image
FROM node:12 as base

# set our working directory
WORKDIR /app

FROM base as development

# copy over dependecy manifests to install
COPY package*.json ./

# install production dependencies and copy them to a temp folder, we will use this for the final build step
RUN npm install --production
RUN cp -R node_modules /tmp/node_modules

# Install all dependcies
RUN npm install

# Copy source code
COPY . ./

# lint, unit test, e2e test and build our app
FROM development as builder
RUN npm run lint
RUN npm run test:cov
RUN npm run test:e2e
RUN npm run build

# release includes bare miniumum to run the app
FROM base as release
COPY --from=builder /tmp/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./

# Run the web service on container boot
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

And finally, my package.json uses the following script to start the application:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "prod:migration": "npm i -g typeorm && npm run typeorm:migration",
    "start:prod": "npm run prod:migration && node dist/src/main",
    "typeorm:migration": "ts-node --transpile-only ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run",
    "typeorm:revert": "ts-node --transpile-only ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:revert"
    ...
},
```

When deploying, I'd get errors saying typeorm/ts-node weren't found. Some minor tweaking would allow the app to deploy successfully but without any migrations run successfully. I was wondering if I was on the right path or if there were any changes I could make in order to have the migrations run successfully on the application startup.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but if you only want to run migrations on application startup you can use the [`migrationsRun`](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options/common-connection-options) config of typeorm

Comment: I should have noted that I have tried to use that flag, but haven't had any success in it actually running the migrations. Not sure if it's failing to load the migrations from their directory, but I wasn't able to successfully use that property either. I was hoping manually calling the process would help my debugging process. Definitely want to use `migrationsRun` eventually